# Automatically register user into Youtube or Flickr

Tags: youtube, flickr

I would like to give the posibility to my website users of entering their email, name, etc. only one time, and make it possible to register with those credentials to Youtube or Flickr direcctly. Is it possible to do it with some of their apis?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot register a user to Flickr. Only flickr can do that. In fact, in the API you're not even handling the password. It's all done on flickr's turf. 
I guess Youtube is the same (it would make sense since Google also uses Oauth).